# Trying to write to file using g_file_set_contents

Tags: glib

I just want to use GNOME glib functions to simply write and read a file. I think my syntaxes are wrong in calling the functions. I tried to open a file with g_fopen("filenam.txt", "w"); but it didnt create any file. I also used g_file_set_contents and I am trying to save my Gstring s into a file file.txt with code as

```
static void events_handler(const uint8_t *pdu, uint16_t len, gpointer user_data)
{
    uint8_t *opdu;
    uint16_t handle, i, olen;
    size_t plen;
    //GString *s;
    const gchar *s;
    gssize length;
    length = 100;

    handle = get_le16(&pdu[1]);

    switch (pdu[0]) {
    case ATT_OP_HANDLE_NOTIFY:
        s = g_string_new(NULL);
        //g_string_printf(s, "Movement data = 0x%04x value: ",handle);
        g_file_set_contents("file.txt", s, 100, NULL);
        break;
        case ATT_OP_HANDLE_IND:
            s = g_string_new(NULL);
            g_string_printf(s, "Indication   handle = 0x%04x value: ",handle);
            break;
        default:
        error("Invalid opcode\n");
        return;
    }

    for (i = 3; i < len; i++)
        g_string_append_printf(s, "%02x ", pdu[i]);

    rl_printf("%s\n", s->str);
    g_string_free(s, TRUE);

    if (pdu[0] == ATT_OP_HANDLE_NOTIFY)
        return;

    opdu = g_attrib_get_buffer(attrib, &plen);
    olen = enc_confirmation(opdu, plen);

    if (olen > 0)
        g_attrib_send(attrib, 0, opdu, olen, NULL, NULL, NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're conflating `GString*` and `gchar*`.  The `g_string_*()` functions expect a `GString*`, and `g_file_set_contents()` expects `gchar*`.  If you want the raw data, use the [`str` field](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Strings.html#GString).

Also, I suggest turning on some more warnings on your compiler, since it really should be complaining during development if you try to do this.  Passing `-Wall` should do the trick…

Comment: ^ I am able to write and read to file but data written seems to be in another format. Please find the question posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33930635/data-written-in-file-using-glibc