# Data written in file using glib

Tags: c, glib

I have a code that writes a number of characters of length `<length>` in a file, using g_file_set_contents. When I open the file, I see some weird characters that seem to be ASCII like @&@@. I assumed that the data might be written in ASCII format, converting from binary, so I used a function to convert from ASCII to binary. I still did not get any resolution after execution.
Here is the code

```
#include <glib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{

 FILE *file = g_fopen("Multicore","w");
 gchar *contents = 00001111;
 gchar **contents1 = NULL;
 GError *err = NULL;
 g_file_set_contents ("Multicore", &contents, 8, &err);
 g_assert ((contents == NULL && err != NULL) || (contents != NULL && err == NULL));
 if (err != NULL)
  {
    g_assert (contents == NULL);
    fprintf (stderr, "Unable to read file: %s\n", err->message);
    g_error_free (err);
  } 
 else
  {
    g_assert (contents != NULL);
  }
  int p = g_ascii_digit_value(contents);
  if (g_ascii_isdigit (contents))
    return contents - '0';
  return -1;
  g_printf(" The output is %c \n", contents);
  return 0;
}
```

I get the output correctly as

The output is 00001111

Comment: You may want to compile with `-Wall -Werror` and fix the warnings as I built  your code and I get about 12 warnings that look severe enough to produce unexpected results

Comment: I use this command.  gcc `pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0` new_compile.c `pkg-config --libs glib-2.0` Should I put -Wall and -Werror in the end of the command? Apparently I am getting around 12 13 errors which didnt show up earlier.

Comment: `glibc` usually refer to GNU libc. `glib` is a package from GTK (usable without GUI)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You literally have a number of errors. Compiling with warnings, as suggested, will help direct your attention to what needs to be fixed. Addressing the most significant first (the compiler's inability to find `g_fopen`) e.g.:

```
debug.c:12:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘g_fopen’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  FILE *file = g_fopen("Multicore","w");
  ^
debug.c:12:15: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  FILE *file = g_fopen("Multicore","w");
           ^
```

Which tells you you are missing an include(s) file. A quick check would tell you to include: `

```
#include <glib-object.h>
#include <glib/gstdio.h>
```

After fixing the includes, you would find a number of additional warnings to address:

```
debug.c: In function ‘main’:
debug.c:13:20: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
gchar *contents = 00001111;
                    ^
debug.c:16:2: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘g_file_set_contents’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
g_file_set_contents ("Multicore", &contents, 8, &err);
^
In file included from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib.h:50:0,
                from debug.c:1:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gfileutils.h:91:10: note: expected ‘const gchar *’ but argument is of type ‘gchar **’
gboolean g_file_set_contents (const gchar *filename,
        ^
debug.c:28:3: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘g_ascii_digit_value’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
int p = g_ascii_digit_value(contents);
^
In file included from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib.h:81:0,
                from debug.c:1:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gstrfuncs.h:96:23: note: expected ‘gchar’ but argument is of type ‘gchar *’
gint                  g_ascii_digit_value  (gchar    c) G_GNUC_CONST;
                    ^
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gstrfuncs.h:67:19: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
((g_ascii_table[(guchar) (c)] & G_ASCII_DIGIT) != 0)
                ^
debug.c:29:7: note: in expansion of macro ‘g_ascii_isdigit’
if (g_ascii_isdigit (contents))
    ^
debug.c:30:5: warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
    return contents - '0';
    ^
debug.c:32:3: warning: format ‘%c’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘gchar *’ [-Wformat=]
g_printf(" The output is %c \n", contents);
^
```

Addressing each in turn gets you to the point that your program compiles with only warning for *unused variables* which will not effect its operation:

```
#include <glib.h>
#include <glib-object.h>
#include <glib/gstdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{

    FILE *file = g_fopen ("Multicore", "w");
    gchar *contents = "00001111";
    gchar **contents1 = NULL;
    GError *err = NULL;
    g_file_set_contents ("Multicore", contents, 8, &err);
    g_assert ((contents == NULL && err != NULL)
            || (contents != NULL && err == NULL));
    if (err != NULL) {
        g_assert (contents == NULL);
        fprintf (stderr, "Unable to read file: %s\n", err->message);
        g_error_free (err);
    } else {
        g_assert (contents != NULL);
    }
    int p = g_ascii_digit_value (*contents);
    if (g_ascii_isdigit (*contents))
        return *contents - '0';
    return -1;
    g_printf (" The output is %c \n", *contents);
    return 0;
}
```

**Use**

```
$ ./bin/debug
```

**Output**

```
$ cat Multicore
00001111
```

As desired with no additional or strange characters.

**Full Compile String w/Warnings Enabled**

The full compile string on the laptop I'm using (openSuSE 13.1), makes use of `pkg-config` to secure the necessary include/lib paths as well as the libraries themselves. The compile string used was:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Ofast -o bin/debug debug.c \
`pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0`
```

If you do not have `pkgconfig`, the full compile string expanded (with line continuations inserted for readability) would be:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Ofast -o bin/debug debug.c -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 \
-I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 \
-I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/libdrm \
-I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/libpng16 \
-I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 \
-I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/freetype2 \
-lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 \
-lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lfontconfig \
-lfreetype
```

Comment: Hi David--doing your usual great job, I see.  OP asked [me] about -Wall placement.  I was going to do a similar "full service" cleanup and post it, but now, not necessary.  I would have added an addendum about how to create a reasonable Makefile.  Maybe, you could add this to your post because it's not worth a separate answer by me just for that

Comment: OK, I'll post the compile string. I use somewhat of a different system that creates a *makefile-on-the-fly* on a per-directory basis via a build script and local `bldflags` contains the necessary include and lib paths, so I don't have a full makefile `:)`

Comment: I do something very similar [exactly similar, actually--build system written in perl that has similarities to `scons`].  If I met you IRL, I'd probably call you "friend" :-). I only speak Makefiles for SO.  I have built up a rules.mk but it still needs a bit of my perl infrastructure, which is why I didn't post it.

Comment: It is embarrassingly incomplete, but I put a copy of the *makefile-on-the-fly* up at [**pastebin - gcc build system (alias to 'g')**](http://pastebin.com/Rj6uS9CZ). I simply drop a `bldflags` file in the current directory containing additional flags/libs needed for that project. For my *gtk2* dir, I have everything beginning with `-pthread ...` in the `bldflags` file. Give me any suggestions you have `:)`

Comment: It'll take a bit, but I will look at it.  I've been building my perl script infrastructure for a while (e.g. 250,000 lines).  The build part is 10,000 lines but the core library is 30,000 lines.  It installs with a single command, but ... Ain't too portable.  However, I did post the core definition files for the build scripts.  These are .ini style format, and work like system's config files  See http://pastebin.com/Pae5RgD8  Each program has it's own `[program_name]` section and the build can done from any directory as build system knows full paths to top source dirs

Comment: Holy 5h1t... We are not even in the same universe there. Mine is simply a quick and dirty typing saver that allows building most small project with `g exename source.c [addn'l sources...  flags...]`. Little more than a gcc version check for optimization flag, arrangement of the compile string, check/source any additional libraries/includes and build. Nothing on a grand scale such as you describe. I'll make a wager... I bet it takes me a lot longer to digest yours, than you mine `:)`

Comment: You are correct sir!  Mine is a "build all programs with all possible combinations of options, for all possible platforms, including device drivers, and all possible cross-build toolchains, all in parallel, and perform all unit test suites".  Like BSD's "make world".  It's modelled on what a corp (e.g. MS) does to do a nightly build of everything they have.  Instead of makefiles scattered about, just a few files that have entries for given program.  The "sections" can "inherit" from one another.  The "default" is like the fundamental "base class" that all others derive from, an OO makefile